# How to hide the parent directory with .gitignore for a softlinked folder

Tags: linux, git

I have a directory structure where
I linked `run` with `ln -s`:

```
drwxrwxr-x     .
lrwxrwxrwx     ├── run -> /home/xxx/.local/share/development/minecraft/vanilla_run
drwxrwxr-x     └── src
```

Is there a way to ignore `run` with a `.gitignore` inside `run` or any other way to automatically ignore the run folder when I add it to a project.

I don't want to use the projects `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude`.

I tried `.gitignore` with

```
*
*/
../run
../run/
./
run
```

Comment: I don't think that can be done. The instruction to ignore needs to be in the containing folder/project, exactly where you say you don't want it: in `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude`.

Comment: Can I ask at a higher level, what you're trying to accomplish, and why you don't want to use those two options? Maybe someone will have an idea for a different way to approach the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.